# Cannot invoke the latest Common Dialogs when using custom styles, only when using Windows theme

Tags: delphi

I have an application which uses Windows11 Modern styles (Light and Dark).

It seems that any of the custom styles default the Common Dialogs to use the old-style dialogs, which means the dialogs do not show mapped network drives, etc. If I revert to the default Windows theme, all the dialogs correctly show the mapped network drives.

I have `UseLatestCommonDialogs:=true`, but this seems to be ignored when using themes.  Tried before and after setting the `StyleManager` to the appropriate style.

How can I force the application to show this is the dialog style?
[image]

This is the dialog style I get when using "Windows11 Modern Light"
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using [vcl-style-utils](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils)

This library supports Classic and Modern styles and works well on hi-Res screens.

Comment: Yes his VCL Style Utils units are great! I dont understand Embarcadero didn't add these (with permission from the Author) to the VCL, this problem still exists in D11. Not only for common dialogs but also for highligh colors in Edits and comboboxes.